# Aggregate yearly data based on different months using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table 'Amounts' where I have the monthly payments of customers. Every customer has a row for each payment he has made. I want to aggregate their payments yearly starting from the month they paid first. For example in the table given below, for userID 132, I want to aggregate his payments starting from month 9 of 2019 to month 8 of 2020 (one full year) as one row and then again from month 9 of 2020 to the next as another row.

Basically I want the yearly amounts of users as rows based on the month they joined. I'm not sure of how to aggregate this data using SQL and would appreciate help here.

Sample table (if it's simpler, I can combine the year and month column as a date column in the raw data itself) >

```
+--------+------+-------+--------+
| userID | year | month | amount |
+--------+------+-------+--------+
| 132    | 2019 | 9     | 836    |
+--------+------+-------+--------+
| 132    | 2019 | 10    | 702    |
+--------+------+-------+--------+
| 132    | 2019 | 11    | 161    |
+--------+------+-------+--------+
| 132    | 2019 | 12    | 955    |
+--------+------+-------+--------+
| 132    | 2020 | 1     | 969    |
+--------+------+-------+--------+
| 132    | 2020 | 2     | 977    |
+--------+------+-------+--------+
| 132    | 2020 | 3     | 986    |
+--------+------+-------+--------+
| 132    | 2020 | 4     | 639    |
+--------+------+-------+--------+
| 132    | 2020 | 5     | 411    |
+--------+------+-------+--------+
| 132    | 2020 | 6     | 302    |
+--------+------+-------+--------+
| 132    | 2020 | 7     | 929    |
+--------+------+-------+--------+
| 132    | 2020 | 8     | 884    |
+--------+------+-------+--------+
| 132    | 2020 | 9     | 644    |
+--------+------+-------+--------+
| 132    | 2020 | 10    | 640    |
+--------+------+-------+--------+
| 132    | 2020 | 11    | 121    |
+--------+------+-------+--------+
| 132    | 2020 | 12    | 980    |
+--------+------+-------+--------+
| 1447   | 2020 | 11    | 356    |
+--------+------+-------+--------+
| 1447   | 2020 | 12    | 351    |
+--------+------+-------+--------+
```

Sample Output (the year cycle column here is just to indicate which year the total belongs since the users joined).>

```
+--------+------------+----------------------+
| userID | Year Cycle | Current Total Amount |
+--------+------------+----------------------+
| 132    | 1          | 8751                 |
+--------+------------+----------------------+
| 132    | 2          | 2385                 |
+--------+------------+----------------------+
| 1447   | 1          | 707                  |
+--------+------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Please, add the [tag of your DBMS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info). And do not use images of data, paste it as plain text.

Comment: select sum(value), year, month from table group by year, month

Comment: @astentx Thanks. I've made the edits you suggested.

Comment: @WalterVehoeven I don't think that would give me the desired result. I want a row indicating sum(value) over the first 12 months, then another row indicating the sum for next 12 months based on whichever month the data starts for each user.

Comment: @DaleK Added a sample output. Still working on the attempt as I'm not sure of how I should go about it

Comment: is the `sample output` correspond to the sample data ?

Comment: @Squirrel Yes. It does. The year cycle is just an extra column I've added in the output to indicate how many iterations of sum of amount has been (viz. how many years the user has stayed on)

Comment: please show for UserID 1447, how to get 1402 ?

Comment: @Squirrel I'm sorry. The total numbers dont correspond to the data in the table as you pointed out. Fixing it. For userID 1447, the total should be 351+356 = 707

Comment: @Squirrel I've edited the sample output to coresspond to the no.s in the samples table. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [row_number()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to generate a sequence a number for each user and then group every 12 as 1 cycle

```
select userId, cycle, sum(amount)
from
(
    select *, 
           cycle = (row_number() over (partition by userId 
                                           order by year, month) - 1) / 12 + 1
    from   Amounts
) t
group by userId, cycle
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e5f9ee72f5a451d2cf6e85c4555bc45f)

Comment: If `OP` is having `one and only one` record for `each month` `after joining` then only this code will work.

Answer (score 2):

References -

1. [Common Table Expressions (CTE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-common-table-expressions-cte/
2. [SELECT - OVER Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Use `CTE` like below to get your desired outcome.

Get date column to get minimum date for each user with first CTE `AmountWithDate`.

Then create another `CTE` `AmountWithYearDifference` using previous `CTE` `AmountWithDate` to get `years` from user's first transaction. Have to use `over(partition by ...)`

Then use `AmountWithYearDifference` with `GROUP BY` with `userid` & `dt` and `SUM(Amount)` to get desired output.

```
;WITH AmountWithDate AS (
    SELECT *, DATEFROMPARTS(year, month, 1) AS dt 
    FROM Amounts
)
, AmountWithYearDifference AS (
    SELECT *, DATEDIFF(MONTH, (min(dt) over(partition by userid)), dt) / 12 AS years
    FROM AmountWithDate
)
SELECT userid, 
        min(dt) AS dt, DATEPART(MONTH, MIN(dt)) as month, 
        DATEPART(YEAR, MIN(dt)) as year, 
        sum(Amount)
FROM AmountWithYearDifference
GROUP BY userid, years
```

---

**Edit** if you already have `date` column then no need to have first `CTE` and you can go with directly second `CTE`. I assume that your `date` column name is `dt`.

```
;WITH AmountWithYearDifference AS (
    SELECT *, DATEDIFF(MONTH, (min(dt) over(partition by userid)), dt) / 12 AS years
    FROM Amounts
)
SELECT userid, 
        min(dt) AS dt, DATEPART(MONTH, MIN(dt)) as month, 
        DATEPART(YEAR, MIN(dt)) as year, 
        sum(Amount)
FROM AmountWithYearDifference
GROUP BY userid, years
```

If you are not familiar with `CTE` and wish to go with `inner sql query` then you can write query like below. Just write `query` from `CTE` in `inner query` as below.

```
SELECT userid, 
        min(dt) AS dt, DATEPART(MONTH, MIN(dt)) as month, 
        DATEPART(YEAR, MIN(dt)) as year, 
        sum(Amount)
FROM (
    SELECT *, DATEDIFF(MONTH, (min(dt) over(partition by userid)), dt) / 12 AS years
    FROM Amounts
)
GROUP BY userid, years
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for this. I'm new to SQL so I'm not well versed with CTE. I see you're creating a date column from the first CTE. If I already create the required date column in the base table instead of having the columns of month and year, would it make the job easier?

Comment: Definitely having column for date would be an advantage. You will only need one `CTE`. I have added few links for reference. CTE is kind of temporary table.